# Что было раньше: арифметика либо письменность? Цифра или буква?

Tags: письменность

По мотивам высказывания "Иногда мне кажется, что грамматика ближе стоит к математике..."

Answer (score 1):

А при чём здесь письменность, если речь о грамматике?Грамматика изучает грамматический строй языка, закономерности построения правильных осмысленных речевых отрезков (словоформ, синтагм, предложений, текстов)Она во многом действительно близка математике. Говоря о письменности, мы имеем в виду алфавит, древние письмена, современную письменность - всё, что написано,письменность - знаковая передача речи, математика тоже отражается в письменности.Цифры могут считаться частью письменности.

Первые написанные цифры, о которых мы имеем достоверные свидетельства, появились в Египте и Месопотамии около 5000 лет назад. Письменность как графическая система появилась примерно к 3300 г. до н.э. в Шумере, к 3000 г. до н.э. в Египте, к 2000 г. до н.э. в Китае.

Comment: Итак, по Вашим сведениям, "написанные цифры" появились раньше, чем "письменность как графическая система".

Answer (score 1):

Смотря что понимать под письменностью, а что под арифметикой. Письменность, как способ передачи информации с помощью графических средств, появилась почти одновременно с современным человеком. Сперва письмо было пиктографическим (рисуночное), затем иероглифическим,  затем трансформировалось, или не трансформировалось в алфавитное.

Первые изображения цифр появились явно позже рисуночного письма, само понятия числа, как абстракции, скорей всего тоже, но нам не известно ни одного народа, который б не умел считать предметы хотя бы до двух. Более того, способностью считать кроме человека обладают и многие другие животные, так что арифметика, в значении "счёт", появилась раньше письменного языка.

Какое отношение эти сведения имеют к грамматике, которая как наука действительно скорее относится к точным, чем гуманитарным, я не знаю.

Comment: Итак, по Вашим сведениям, "изображения цифр появились" "позже рисуночного (пиктографического) письма".

P.S. Обратил внимание на высказывание: "Способностью считать кроме человека обладают и многие другие животные, так что арифметика, в значении "счёт", появилась раньше письменного языка".

P.P.S. Любопытно, какие животные обладают способностью писать?